# How to order by eager loaded relationship in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

The code below works perfectly and displays all products with discounts in JSON Format for my API. But I want the result ordered by id in the discounts table. Something like `orderBy('discount.id', 'desc')`. Can anyone provide a solution for this? How it is possible to use orderBy with `id` column in `discount` table using `has()`?

```
public function promotions()
{
    return $this->prepareResult(true, Product::has('discount')->where([
        'company_id' => 1, 'is_active' => 1
    ])->with('category')->with('discount')->get(), [], "All Promotions");
}
```

Comment: Let me get this straight - you want to order products by `discount.id`? You'd need to use join for that.

Comment: Do you want the product list order based on discounts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function within your `with` statement:

```
public function promotions()
{
    return $this->prepareResult(true, Product::has('discount')
        ->where(['company_id'=> 1, 'is_active'=>1])
        ->with('category')
        ->with(['discount' => function ($query) {
            return $query->orderBy('id','DESC');
        }])->get(), [],"All Promotions");
}
```

You can read about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) in the documentation.

Comment: I am looking for DESC order, and I have already tried this method. I am still not getting ids in descending order!!! :-(

Comment: did you change the `orderby` to DESC?

Comment: This sorts the `discounts`, not the `products`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the collection method route instead of Alex's answer (which is also valid), you can just continue to chain collection methods after get. Since you included the with(), you can do

`->get()->sortBy('discount.id')`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby

Not related to your question, but wanted to point out that you can pass multiple arguments to with() so that you don't call it twice.

```
Product::has('discount')->where(['company_id'=> 1, 'is_active'=>1])->with('discount', 'category')->get()
```

Comment: Tried your method using sortByDesc() method, but still getting not getting descending ids.

Comment: If you dd(Product::has('discount')->where(['company_id'=> 1, 'is_active'=>1])->with('discount', 'category')->get()->sortByDesc('discount.id')->pluck('discount.id')->toArray()) what shows up?

Answer (score 0):

As DevK mentioned, you need to do a join and then you can sort your products by that. The trick here is that you join the **discounts** table to your **products** table, but only select the **id** column (named as discount_id) from your **discounts** table so you can sort by those records.

In the below example, I assumed that your

- **Category** model's table is **categories**
- **Product** model's table is **products**
- **Discount** model's table is **discounts**
- **products** table references a **discount.id** as **discount_id**

This code will return every column from the **products** table plus a **discount_id** column, which you can ignore, it's only there for the sorting. It will also keep it as a collection with the relationships that you stated above.

```
public function promotions()
{
    return $this->prepareResult(
        true,
        Product::has('discount')
            ->where(['company_id' => 1, 'is_active' => 1])
            ->with('category')
            ->with('discount')
            ->selectRaw('products.*, discounts.id as discount_id')
            ->join('discount', 'products.discount_id', '=', 'discounts.id')
            ->orderBy('discount_id', 'DESC')
            ->get(),
        [],
        "All Promotions"
    );
}
```